# How to save Viewer Pane as image through command line?

Tags: r, rstudio

Let's say I have the following HTML viewed in the Viewer Pane

```
tempDir <- tempfile()
dir.create(tempDir)
htmlFile <- file.path(tempDir, "index.html")
write('<h1> Content</h1>', htmlFile, append = TRUE)
write('<h2> Content</h2>', htmlFile, append = TRUE)
write('lorem ipsum...', htmlFile, append = TRUE)
viewer <- getOption("viewer")
viewer(htmlFile)
```

When I have this html in the Viewer Pane, I can click on the "Save as image" button:

[image]

And I have the html content as a png, for example :

[image]

Is there a way to do this with the command line? I know about `rstudioapi::savePlotAsImage()`, so I'm looking for a kind of `saveViewerAsImage`.

**Edit**: I know we can do this with the {webshot} package, but I'm looking for the RStudio function that does that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a proposal. The strategy is the following:

1. let the viewer build the `png`
2. send the `png` from the viewer to R

### Let the viewer build the `png`

A [`canvas` image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas) possesses a [`.toDataURL()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) that returns a data URI containing the representation of the image in `png` format (we also can get a `jpeg` format).

The [`html2canvas` library](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) can be used to take a screenshot: this library renders the current page as a `canvas` image.

So, one can combine these two functions in the viewer:

- take a screenshot with `html2canvas`
- transform this screenshot to `png` using `.toDataURL()`

However, the `html2canvas` library uses JavaScript [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)s that are not supported by the (Windows version) RStudio viewer: a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Polyfill) is required.

### Send the `png` from the viewer to R

This task can be achieved using [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API).

The `httpuv` package can be used to create a webserver. This server will serve a `HTML` page that will be opened in the `RStudio` viewer.

A WebSocket communication is established between the `httpuv` server and the RStudio viewer.

From the R command line, one can send a WebSocket message to the RStudio viewer: receiving this message, the viewer takes the screenshot and send it back to the server.

### The code

I'm sorry, this code is quite long for a SO answer.

```
library(httpuv)

# Initialize variables
png <- NULL
websocket <- NULL

# Download Javascript libraries
polyfill_promise <- readLines('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/es6-promise/dist/es6-promise.auto.min.js')
html2canvas <- readLines('https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js')

# Configure the httpuv server
app <- list(
  call = function(req) {
    list(
      status = 200L,
      headers = list(
        'Content-Type' = 'text/html'
      ),
      body = paste0(collapse = "\r\n",
                    c("<!DOCTYPE html>",
                      "<html>",
                      "<head>",
                      # polyfill the RStudio viewer to support JavaScript promises
                      '<script type="text/javascript">',
                      polyfill_promise,
                      "</script>",
                      # use html2canvas library
                      '<script type="text/javascript">',
                      html2canvas,
                      "</script>",
                      "</head>",
                      "<body>",
                      html_body,
                      "</body>",
                      '<script type="text/javascript">',
                      # Configure the client-side websocket connection:
                      'var ws = new WebSocket("ws://" + location.host);',
                      # When a websocket message is received:
                      "ws.onmessage = function(event) {",
                      # Take a screenshot of the HTML body element
                      "  html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {",
                      # Transform it to png
                      "    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();",
                      # Send it back to the server
                      "    ws.send(dataURL);",
                      "  });",
                      "};",
                      "</script>",
                      "</html>"
                    )
      )
    )
  },
  # Configure the server-side websocket connection
  onWSOpen = function(ws) {
    # because we need to send websocket message from the R command line:
    websocket <<- ws
    # when a websocket message is received from the client
    ws$onMessage(function(binary, message) {
      png <<- message
    })
  }
)

# From your question:
html_body <- c(
  '<h1> Content</h1>', 
  '<h2> Content</h2>', 
  'lorem ipsum...'
)

# Start the server:
server <- startDaemonizedServer("0.0.0.0", 9454, app)

# Open the RStudio viewer:
rstudioapi::viewer("http://localhost:9454")
# Wait to see the result...

# Send a websocket message from the command line:
websocket$send("go") # send any message

# Write the png image to disk:
writeBin(
  RCurl::base64Decode(
    gsub("data:image/png;base64,", "", png), 
    "raw"
  ), 
  "screenshot.png"
)

# Close the websocket connection
websocket$close()

# Stop the server
stopDaemonizedServer(server)
```

Comment: I feel `wsUrl` could be `location.host`?

Comment: @YihuiXie Good catch! Since that simplifies the answer, I've updated it. Thanks for the compliment and the bounty!